# Gravitational acceleration of asteroids

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, celestial-mechanics, escape-velocity

If an asteroid is moving through space at a speed that exceeds escape velocity of the earth and that asteroid is on a collision course with the earth will the asteroid Accelerate as it falls into the Earth's gravity well?

Ie: is there a speed limit for Earths gravitational acceleration imparted upon nearby bodies?

Comment: escape velocity doesn't mean anything when the asteroid is going towards the earth. It would simply be accelerated more as it got closer to Earth. $a \propto \frac{1}{r^2}$

Comment: This should be aptly answered in "the dynamics of an asteroid" and there is no need to repeat it here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dynamics_of_an_Asteroid#/media/File:The_Dynamics_of_An_Asteroid.jpg

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of simplicity (at the expense of real-life accuracy), let's assume that an asteroid is already travelling at some speed $v_0$ directly toward the Earth, and it never deviates away from that direct line path (despite the revolution of the Earth around the Sun). Let's also assume the distance from Earth is very large compared to the radius of Earth ($R_E$), and the Sun's gravitational field doesn't affect the speed.  In that case we can say
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2=\frac{GmM_E}{R_E}.$$

Now we also know that the escape velocity for Earth can be found using conservation of mechanical energy in a gravitational field:
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_e^2=\frac{GmM}{R_E}.$$

Combining these we get 
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2=\frac{1}{2}mv_e^2$$ or 
$$v_f=\sqrt{v_e^2+v_0^2},$$
which is larger than $v_e$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the escape velocity with terminal velocity. While for the local velocity the limit is only the speed of light, terminal velocity is achieved [much sooner](https://www.google.com/search?q=asteroid%20terminal%20velocity) because of the air resistance. The equation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) and depends on the shape, size and density of the asteroid.

For particles travelling near the speed of light you have to divide the radial component of the gravitational acceleration by [γ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor)³ and the transversal component by [γ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) to calculate the local proper velocity - which makes sure you never accelerate beyond c.

Multiply the proper velocity with √(1-[rs](https://www.google.com/search?q=schwarzschild%20radius)/r) to get the coordinate velocity in the system of an observer at infinity - then the motion stops when the time dilation becomes infinite like on the horizon of a black hole.

Maybe there are some flaws in my calculation but in principle that's how it should work, more or less.

Answer (score -6):

No, you won't speed up and the fastest speed the earth can accelerate you to is at escape velocity.

Comment: No reason the asteroid can't be accelerated to a speed higher than the escape velocity.

Comment: Well if your just thinking of gravity itself it can't speed it up faster then ecsape velocity because it's gravity is only 9.807 m/s² and as you get closer to the surface you speed up because you are getting closer to the center of mass but you can't ecsactly get there because there it

Comment: Acceleration due to gravity is not velocity-dependent. It is mass and distance dependent. $a \propto \frac{GM_{earth}}{r^2}$ so this is incorrect, it would continue to gain speed up until it hits the surface of the earth.

Comment: So there are apparently more than one thought paths expressed here.  That begs another question.  If the asteroid were traveling near c speed before encountering  the gravity well of the (rather than earth, a black hole it is on a collision course to hit), can the asteroid be accelerated beyond c by the gravity effect of the black hole? Ie:  is there any extreme speed limit to gravitational acceleration?  Or: why not let a black hole accelerate our asteroid beyond c?

Comment: @JohnG The point at which the object passes the event horizon is the point at which its velocity reaches $c$.  As is well-known this point is in the indefinite future for distant observers.